при билде апк, выдает ошибку, не видит зависимости gradle
скачал сурсы лаунчера мобильного, при билде выдает следующий код ошибки:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not find ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.hzy:libp7zip:1.7.0.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.dinuscxj:circleprogressbar:1.3.6.
Required by:
project :app

шо делать

Возможно исходники старые и либы были в jCenter выложены, а он теперь не работает. Можно поковыряться и поискать эти либы в других местах (не факт что авторы их куда-то ещё выкладывали) или вручную из кода эти либы убрать, чем-то заменив, либо найти исходники либ и в проект их явно встроить. В общем это долго, сложно и имеет смысл не пытаться это вообще делать, а поискать другие исхоники. Ну это если проект устаревший.
